# how to add one row in datagrid in c# on class constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In a project created using C# WPF, I am using a datagrid to give the user an empty table that the user has to fill in but I could not add rows to my datagrid. I would also like to give the user the opportunity to add a blank line either by clicking on a button or completing a line. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting [DataGrid.CanUserAddRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) which is set to `true` by default. But this feature requires that the DataGrid's `ItemsSource` must be set to an editable collection (not a read only). Also items of the collection must have a parameterless constructor.